# how to set SSH locale

Tags: ssh, locale, yocto

I have a box running Poky Linux Rocko-2.4.2 with BusyBox. I set the locale to US English UTF-8 (en_US.UTF-8).  If I log in as root directly at the console and execute: locale, I get the expected output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

If I SSH into the box as root and execute: locale, I also get the expected output as seen above. I  am writting a python script for testing various OS attributes, the system locale being one of them. I am using the python Paramiko module for the SSH connection; same credentials: root user & password.  However, when the script executes, it returns this:

```
LANG=""
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=""
```

Searching around I found [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/fix-ssh-locale-environment-variable-error) and tried method 2 setting `AcceptEnv no` in the poky boxe's sshd_config, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.  The locale has to be set correctly on the box, meaning that the solution cannot involve changing my ssh configuration like method 3 from the link above.

Have I just not actually configured the locale on the poky box correctly, or...? If I navigate to: /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/, there are 2 files present: gtk30.mo & gtk30-properties.mo; does that sound correct?
I didn't include the python code because I honestly didn't think it was the culprit, but if comments think other wise I will add in an edit.

Comment: hm, this is not really an answer, but: I can see how an automation tool like Paramiko would want to always set the locale to POSIX or just C; things that you do in automation shouldn't interact with the user, anyway.

Comment: When you use Paramiko or even if you execute a remote command like `ssh root@box locale`, you'll get a *non-interactive session*, which will usually bypass much of the normal environment setup - perhaps the locale settings too.

Comment: thanks for the comments; all good points. It doesn't answer my question but it is a work around at lease. rather than issuing 'locale' in the python script, issuing the command 'localectl status' returns the desired output: System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8